# It it safe to have a 15 amp GFCI outlet on a 50 amp GFCI breaker?

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker, gfci

My friend just got rid of her hot tub. The person that took it put an outlet where the tub was. He put in a 15 amp GFCI at the outlet but left the 50 amp GFCI breaker in the panel box.

Is this sufficient or trouble waiting to happen?

Answer (score 6):

This is trouble, but easily solved.  Simply swap out the 50 ampere GFCI breaker, for a 15 ampere GFCI breaker.

You'll possibly have to use pigtails to connect to the breaker, as it may not accept the size wire used for the existing circuit.

---

As "subpanels" seem to be quite popular around here, I'm surprised it hasn't been suggested yet.  You could always install a second panel where the tub used to be, then install a 15 or 20 ampere breaker to feed the receptacle.

Comment: Can you elaborate what the trouble is? The initial setup seems fine to me, assuming the cable up to the outlet is rated for 50A.

Comment: @jpa: +1. According to http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/81251/2815 - the wire from the outlet to a 15A appliance is not protected against overcurrent by a typical GFCI outlet. In the situation described in the question, a fault in an appliance could therefore pull up to 50A through a 15A appliance lead and set fire to it and anything nearby. (P.S. this is why UK plugs are fused)

Comment: I wasn't sure if the GFCI acted like a breaker or not. Now I know. Thanks! I'll let them know it can still pull 50 amps and can be dangerous.

Comment: I think you -- or really the OP -- should clarify that it's a 50 A  **breaker**, not a GFCI, in the panel.

Comment: It could be a GFCI breaker. It's safely assumed that it's a breaker of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

You'd also need to change the breaker, because the 50A circuit is probably 240V. You wouldn't want to *simply* connect those wires to a receptacle, unless it's a NEMA 6 type.

In any case you need to use a 15A breaker (or a 20A breaker if there are 2 or more receptacles, or you use a 20A receptacle which is downward compatible with 15A plugs).

It's possible the hot tub was connected 120/240 with a neutral.  If that's the case, you can use one hot and the neutral just fine.  In fact, you can re-use the neutral with the other hot, and get 2 full circuits.  That's called a multi-wire branch circuit.

Comment: They'd need to provide a 15A breaker to protect the receptacle though (can't put a receptacle on a tap conductor)